# PostrgreSQL 8.4: Summation by account numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, postgresql-8.4

I am doing some report on financial accounts, and I need to sum values at levels depending on the initial numbers...
For example sum all values for account starting with 0 (01, 011, 012..), or starting with 1 (1, 10, 111...), or starting with 111 (111,1112,1113...) etc.

Here is simplified sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE account(id, acctNo, credit) AS (
    VALUES
       (1, '01', 100)
      ,(2, '011', 200)
      ,(3, '0112', 300)
      ,(4, '014', 400)
      ,(5, '0144', 500)
      ,(6, '0148', 600)
      ,(7, '01120', 100)
      ,(8, '01121', 100)
      ,(9, '0140', 50)
      ,(10,'02', 50)
      ,(11,'021', 50)
      ,(12,'1', 50)
      ,(13,'10', 100)
      ,(15,'100', 50)    
      ,(14,'1021', 50)
      ,(16,'202', 50)
      ,(17,'221', 50)
      ,(18,'4480', 50)
      ,(19,'447', 50)
      ,(20,'5880', 50)
    )
```

**I managed to do it but it is kinda robust SQL, is there some better solution?**
Here is code:

```
WITH
    a AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(acctNo,1,1) AS LEVEL,
    SUM(credit)  AS sum1 FROM account GROUP BY LEVEL
    ORDER BY LEVEL),
    b AS
   (SELECT SUBSTRING(acctNo,1,2) AS level2,
    SUM(credit) FROM account GROUP BY level2
    ORDER BY level2),
        c AS
   (SELECT SUBSTRING(acctNo,1,3) AS level3,
    SUM(credit) FROM account GROUP BY level3
    ORDER BY level3),
    d AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(acctNo,1,4) AS level4,
    SUM(credit) FROM account GROUP BY level4
    ORDER BY level4),
     e AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(acctNo,1,5) AS level5,
    SUM(credit) FROM account GROUP BY level5
    ORDER BY level5)

 SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT a.* FROM a
 UNION (SELECT b.* FROM b WHERE char_length(level2)>=2)
 UNION (SELECT c.* FROM c WHERE char_length(level3)>=3)
 UNION (SELECT d.* FROM d WHERE char_length(level4)>=4)
 UNION (SELECT e.* FROM e WHERE char_length(level5)>=5)) a
 ORDER BY LEVEL
```

This is only for 5 levels(five-digit numbers)...Is there some generic solution? What if tomorrow I'll need for 6 levels, etc...

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/3fec4/6)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should learn about 1NF, first ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yay generate_series!

```
SELECT substring(a.acctNo from 1 for g.g) as level, sum(a.credit)    
FROM account a, generate_series(1,5) g
where length(a.acctNo) >= g.g
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: +1 . . . I very much like this solution, although I do prefer `cross join` to the use of a `,` in the `from` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Heh, I just thought about this monstrosity: `SELECT substring(a.acctNo from 1 for generate_series(1,length(a.acctno))) as level, sum(a.credit) FROM account a group by 1 order by 1`. Somewhat "cleaner", possibly more performant, but a lot harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

To make maniek's answer generic:

```
with levels as (
    select g
    from generate_series(
        1,
        (select max(length(acctNo)) from account)
    ) g
)
select substring(acctNo from 1 for l.g) as level, sum(a.credit)    
from account a, levels l
where length(acctNo) >= l.g
group by 1
order by 1
```